# How do I install VMD on Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: 15.04, install-from-source, vmd

I have been trying to install VMD (if it helps here's the installation guide in PDF format: http://www.ks.uiuc.edu/Research/vmd/current/ig.pdf) on my 32 bit 15.04 installation. I have extracted the tarball and run `./configure` in the directory, at which point I was informed I was missing some prerequisites, or at least that's what I interpret this output as:

```
using configure.options: LINUX OPENGL OPENGLPBUFFER FLTK TK ACTC CUDA IMD LIBSBALL XINERAMA XINPUT LIBTACHYON VRPN NETCDF COLVARS TCL PTHREADS SILENT ICC
```

running `make` gives:

```
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found. Stop.
```

Answer (score 6):

Its pretty late, but for future users, I am anyhow answering this. The following worked for me.

```
tar -zxvf vmd........
cd vmd
./configure
cd src
sudo make install
```

In general, after unzipping the file always read the READ ME file. The instructions given there are pretty much direct and more specific to your issues.